# jpa specification criteria builder problem

Tags: postgresql, date, jpa

in
specification criteria builder

```
         //String value=request.getStartDate() //is String like a '28-03-2023'
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
   LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(value.toString(), formatter);
       ZonedDateTime startDate = localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
                     predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("createDate"), startDate));
            
            
            
code in entity class 

@Column(name = "create_date", updatable = false)
@CreatedDate
private ZonedDateTime createDate;
```

here data is present in the database but for input value  startDate=28-03-2023 , i am not getting data as output .. what i am missing in the specification?